# Trying to build Telegram bot with Laravel and am getting this error ReplyWithKeyBoardMethod not available

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

Getting this error from telegram Bot sdk https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/v2.0/docs/keyboards and i want to use the replyKeyboardMarkup method am getting this error

`production.ERROR: Method [ReplyKeyboardMarkup] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method [ReplyKeyboardMarkup] does not exist. at /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/Api.php:98)`

Now I know this is supposed to be a type, not a method but how do go about it is the issue can someone assist.

this is what I did

```
$reply_markup = \Telegram::replyKeyboardMarkup([
            'keyboard' => $keyboard, 
            'resize_keyboard' => true, 
            'one_time_keyboard' => true
        ]);

$response = \Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => 'CHAT_ID', 
            'text' => 'Hello World', 
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `replyKeyboardMarkup` is deprecated so what you will use now is `use use Telegram\Bot\Keyboard\Keyboard;` and then

```
    Keyboard::make([
        'keyboard' => $keyboard, 
        'resize_keyboard' => true, 
        'one_time_keyboard' => true
    ]);
```